# Xcode UICollectionView How To Disable Some Cells by indexpath

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have been trying to figure out how to disable cells in a collectionview by indexpath or by using the cellsforitemsatindexpath method of collectionview. I have the following code below but this only disables the last cell in the loop. I also have the following image for when I run the code in Xcode. So far only the third cell horizontal is disabled on first row at top, but I want to disable or set values to nil the first 3 cells from the top row horizontal. From the image link below, the missing '9' on the third cell indicates that value was set to nil. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell != nil)
    {
        // May not need this
        NSInteger cellIndex = [myObjectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        for (int i = 0; i < rangeNumOfCellsToDisable; i++)
        {
            if (indexPath.row == i)
            {
                // If true, code goes here


            }
            else
            {
                // If not true, code that sets stuff to nil goes here


            }


        }


    }

    return cell;

}
```

Screenshot Image
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzaP1abbReAhMTYtSEh3alFlaGs&usp=sharing

Screenshots: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzaP1abbReAhVzhCeEY2eFZibFE&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please try this solution.

I am assuming that you want first three cells to be disabled or you can have any cells disabled..

in .h file

```
-@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *disableArray;
```

in.m file

```
disableArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[disableArray addObject:@"0"];
[disableArray addObject:@"1"];
[disableArray addObject:@"2"];

    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        CollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell != nil)
        {
            // May not need this
            NSInteger cellIndex = [myObjectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            if([disableArray containsObject:[NSString stringwithformat:@"%d",indexPath.row]])
              {
                //the row which you want to disable do whatever you want over here...Hope this helps.
              }


        }

        return cell;

    }
```

Comment: `NSIndexSet` may be a better than an `NSMutableArray`

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Thank! This worked. But now I am having another issue. I am having to reload the collectionview. I am using [cell setHidden:true]; to disable the cell and it works. But when the cells reload with different data the cells that are affected by the if-statement if([disableArray containsObject:[NSString stringwithformat:@"%d",indexPath.row]]), those cells display random numbers. If any of those numbers match the cells that come in order 1, 2, 3,... then those cells are disabled.

Comment: How can I make sure that I clear all the variables in disableArray? I tried [disableArray removeAllObjects], also using a for-loop that runs through [disableArray count] and sets all elements to 0 but I am still getting random numbers. Please see link from original post for a screenshot.

Comment: Where are you allocating disableArray..before refreshing collection view you just make array nil...

Comment: I have tried in allocating within `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` as well as the function that updates the objects that go into the array, before `cellForItemAtIndexPath` gets called. It is only working the first time I run it. Please check out my first post, I added a second link with more screenshots, thanks.

Comment: sorry for delayed response.. Please try this condition if(indexPath.row<3 && indexPath.section==0) instead of if([disableArray containsObject:[NSString stringwithformat:@"%d",indexPath.row]]) and let me know the result. P.S. I am assuming that you always want first 3 rows disabled.